# How to send parenthesis into pipe bounded by parenthesis?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe, sqlplus

In a Windows .bat file, I can use redirection like this:

```
(echo connect / as sysdba
echo select sysdate from dual;
echo exit
) | sqlplus -s /nolog
```

and it will run (obviously this example does nothing). How do I pass parenthesis into this format for a query something like:

```
(echo connect / as sysdba
echo select trunc(sysdate) from dual;
echo exit
) | sqlplus -s /nolog
```

without blowing up the pipe?

Comment: Escape the closing parenthesis in the echo with a caret `^)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add three carets before closing parenthesis.

```
(
echo connect / as sysdba
echo select trunc(sysdate^^^) from dual;
echo exit
) | more
```

Why?
In the first instance you need one caret to escape the parenthesis to avoid, that the block is closed.

```
( echo test (test^) )
```

But as you used a pipe, the complete construct is packed and transfered to a new command exe.
There you need a second time a caret, but to tranfser this caret you need to add two carets in the original echo.
Therefore you need a total of three.